# Trying to insert a single document with mongoose but is inserting several

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I am currently studying with Udemy but could not get an answer through their forums. I'm creating my own site to try and better understand mongoDB using mongoose, express, EJS. The site has multiple forms. When submitting form data with a post request I am attempting to insert a single record into a database but instead get 3 or 4 duplicate records inserted. When using console.log to check the object being sent it also appears several times, however I have tried to send it only once.

Here is my app.js code:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");


const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static("public"));

// Connect / Create to the Database
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/stationDB", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

// Create a new Schema
const stnSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    name: String
});

const contactSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    message: String
});

// Create a new Model
const Station = mongoose.model("Station", stnSchema);

const Message = mongoose.model("Message", contactSchema);

//Creating an array of items to populate the database
const item1 = {
    name: "item 1"
};

const item2 = {
    name: "item 2"
};

const item3 = {
    name: "item 3"
};

const item4 = {
    name: "item 4"
};

const stationData = [item1, item2, item3, item4];

//Check the database to see if items have already been inserted, if not then insert the initial items
Station.find({}, function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        if (results.length === 0) {
            Station.insertMany(stationData), function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("No records found - adding initial records")
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log("Records already in place - none added")
        }
    }
});


//Routes

// Get Requests

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    
    Station.find({}, function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error: cannot find records for stationList");
        }
        else {
            const stationList = results;
            res.render("index", {stationItems: stationList});
        }
    })
    
});

// Post Requests

app.post("/ticketSales", function(req, res) {
    const formSubmit = req.body;
    const adultCost = parseFloat(formSubmit.adults) * 7.85;
    const childCost = parseFloat(formSubmit.child) * 3.50;
    const totalCost = adultCost + childCost;

    console.log(totalCost);

    res.render("ticketSales", {
        adults: formSubmit.adults, 
        adultCost: adultCost,
        children: formSubmit.child,
        childCost: childCost,
        ticketTotal: totalCost,
    })
});

app.post("/contact", function(req, res) {
    
    const formName = req.body.name;
    const formEmail = req.body.email;
    const formMsg = req.body.message;

    const message = new Message({
        name: formName,
        email: formEmail,
        message: formMsg
    });
    console.log(message);

    message.save();

    res.render("contact");

});


// App Listen 

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Server started, port 3000');  //
});
```

console.log() Output for contact form:

```
$ nodemon app.js
[nodemon] 2.0.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json  
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Server started, port 3000
Records already in place - none added
{
  _id: 5f58a8dad8fe413a204649c7,
  name: 'hobbes',
  email: 'hobbes@gmail.com',
  message: 'messgae\r\n                                '
}
{
  _id: 5f58a8dad8fe413a204649c8,
  name: 'hobbes',
  email: 'hobbes@gmail.com',
  message: 'messgae\r\n                                '
}
{
  _id: 5f58a8dad8fe413a204649c9,
  name: 'hobbes',
  email: 'hobbes@gmail.com',
  message: 'messgae\r\n                                '
}
{
  _id: 5f58a8dad8fe413a204649ca,
  name: 'hobbes',
  email: 'hobbes@gmail.com',
  message: 'messgae\r\n                                '
}
```

Output for Ticket:

```
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Server started, port 3000
Records already in place - none added
7.85
7.85
7.85
7.85
```

I'm still very new to this and learning but any help would be much appreciated. The only progress I have made is to note that the initial records which are used to populate a drop down in a form do not duplicate when inserted / retrieved but the records sent via post requests are effected. I believe it is related to the post request.

Edit:
Here is the html:

```
<form name="contact-form" action="/contact" method="post">
                                
   <label for="contact-name">Name</label>
   <input id="contact-name" name="name" type="text">

   <label for="email">Email</label>
   <input id="email" name="email" type="text">

   <label for="contact-msg">Message</label>
   <textarea name="message" id="contact-msg">

   </textarea>

   <button type="submit" value="contact" name="contactBtn">Submit</button>

  </form>
```

Additionally I have found changing the form submit button from  to  reduces the number of submissions from 4 to 2

Comment: How exactly is the form submitted to `/contacts`? Is it a basic HTML-only form?

Comment: Yes just plain html

Comment: I think your code is submitted the form multiple times. Please show you form code

Comment: Added the HTML code

Comment: Through trial and error I have discovered the culprit is the form's textarea. Removing this solves the multiple submissions problem. I have checked the syntax against online examples and all looks good but the textarea causes the problem regardless.